# Error during image upload: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, file-upload, cloudinary

I'm encountering an issue while trying to upload images to my server using Node.js and Express. Whenever there's an error during the image upload process, I receive the following error message:

```js
Error during image upload: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
```

I've been searching for a solution, but I can't seem to pinpoint the exact cause of this error. This is the uploadController of the NODEJS project using cloudinary:

```js
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
require("dotenv").config();

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.SECRET,
});

exports.uploadImage = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "No file uploaded" });
    }

    const uploadOptions = { resource_type: "auto" };

    cloudinary.uploader
      .upload_stream(uploadOptions, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error("Error uploading image to Cloudinary:", error);
          return res.status(500).json({ error: "Error uploading image" });
        }

        if (!result || !result.secure_url) {
          console.error("Invalid response from Cloudinary:", result);
          return res
            .status(500)
            .json({ error: "Invalid response from Cloudinary" });
        }

        const uploadedImage = {
          public_id: result.public_id,
          secure_url: result.secure_url,
          format: result.format,
          width: result.width,
          height: result.height,
        };

        // Check if the format is supported (e.g., you can add more supported formats as needed)
        const supportedFormats = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"];
        if (!supportedFormats.includes(result.format.toLowerCase())) {
          console.error("Unsupported image format:", result.format);
          return res.status(400).json({ error: "Unsupported image format" });
        }

        res.json({ message: "Image uploaded to Cloudinary", uploadedImage });
      })
      .end(req.file.buffer);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during image upload:", error);
    next(error);
  }
};

// exports.upload = upload.single("image");

exports.getDownloadURLFromCloud = async (req, res, next) => {
  const imageId = req.params.public_id;

  try {
    const result = await cloudinary.api.resource(imageId);

    if (!result.secure_url) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Image not found" });
    }

    const downloadURL = result.secure_url;
    res.json({ downloadURL });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching image from Cloudinary:", error);
    next(error);
  }
};

exports.errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error("Error:", err.message);
  res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
};
```

Also the route of the project is:

```js
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
const unlinkFile = util.promisify(fs.unlink);
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const isAuth = require("../middlewares/isAuth");
const {
  uploadImage,
  getDownloadURLFromCloud,
} = require("../controllers/upload");

const cloudinaryStorage = multer.memoryStorage();
const uploadCloudinary = multer({ storage: cloudinaryStorage });

// @route   GET /upload/image/:key
// @desc    Get image with key
// @access  protected
router.get("/image/:imageId", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURLFromCloud(req.params.key);

    res.status(200).json(downloadURL);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    next(error);
  }
});

router.post(
  "/image",
  isAuth,
  uploadCloudinary.single("image"),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const file = req.file;

      if (!file) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "No file uploaded" });
      }
      const result = await uploadImage(file);
      await unlinkFile(file.path);
      res.status(200).json({ imagePath: `/upload/image/${result.public_id}` });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      next(error);
    }
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

I suspect that the issue might be related to the error handling within the catch block, but I'm not sure how to properly handle this error to avoid the "TypeError" and provide a meaningful response to the client.

Could someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error and suggest a proper way to handle it? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like res is undefined on upload failure. so it can not access res.status. I assume you wont get that error anymore when you first check if res is defined before you call the status() function on it